# Unable to load pdf on browser in React application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pdf, browser

I'm trying to **stream a pdf** which is being sent from a REST API built of nodejs and expressjs. From Client I have a button -> 'View PDF' by clicking on the same , there is a API call made to the server , which in turn makes another API call to a third party API([fixflo-doc](https://api-docs.fixflo.com/1e8173408b186-issue-report)) where the pdf is stored. This API is giving back whole pdf as response , so I'm trying to stream the pdf from node server back to client.
And in client I'm trying to open the pdf in a new tab by getting the response as `{ responseType: "blob" }` . But the issue is , browser is not able to Open the pdf and says **'Failed to load PDF document.'**

[image]

Below is the implementation that i have tried so far -

Node ->
For Route `/api/report` this is the code which is getting executed

```
async streamIssueReport(issueId: string, dest: Writable) {
    const mainUrl = new URL(`${process.env.ISSUE_API_URL}`);
    const httpOptions: RequestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      hostname: mainUrl.hostname,
      path: `/api/v2/issue/${issueId}/report`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.AUTH_TOKEN}`,
      },
      
    };
    StreamResponse(dest, httpOptions);
  }
```

```
import https from 'https';
import { Writable } from 'stream';

function StreamResponse(
  destination: Writable,
  options: string | https.RequestOptions,
) {
  const req = https.request(options, (resp) => {
    resp.pipe(destination);
    resp.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log('error',err);
    });
  });
  req.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('error',err);
  });
  req.end();
}
```

Client side ->

```
Axios.post(
    "/api/report",
    {
      issueId
    },
    { responseType: "blob" }
  )
    .then((resp) => {
      console.log("RESPONSE-->>>",resp)
      const file = new Blob(
        [resp.data], 
        {type: 'application/pdf'});
        const fileURL :any= URL.createObjectURL(file);

      window.open(fileURL)
      console.log("FILEURL->",file instanceof Blob)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
```